# Converting PHP to .Net C#

Tags: c#, php, methods

I am in the process of "re-developing" an application that was started in PHP sometime ago. The developer involved has left the company quite awhile ago and all efforts to contact him have fallen to the wayside.

I do not need help converting the whole site as its quite a simple application. However we are integrating with an API service (who's documentation is rather poor) and I am having problems understanding their dateTime strings.

Here is the excerpt (the only bit) on how they use there datetimes.

"
The datetime is expressed as a number derived from an algorithm using the day month year hour minutes and seconds as follows:

```
date=year<<20; 
date|=month<<16; 
date|=day<<11; 
date|=hour<<6;
date|=minute;
```

To unpack the date from a given number is as follows:

```
year=(date & 0xfff00000) >> 20;
month=(date & 0x000f0000) >> 16;
day=(date & 0x0000f800) >> 11; 
hour=(date & 0x000007c0) >> 6; 
minute=(date & 0x0000003f);
```

"

Now comes my question. The developer (and this is a working example) has created the following PHP Function that converts a timestamp to the required format. I am unsure if bitwise timestamp is a "generic algorithm".

I have tried looking around and couldnt find anything.

```
/**
 * Converts a unixtime stamp to a bitwise timestamp
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $unixtime
 * @return void
 */
function convert_unixtime_to_bitwise($unixtime)
{
    /*$year = date('Y', $unixtime);
    $month = date('m', $unixtime);
    $day = date('j', $unixtime);
    $hour = date('G', $unixtime);
    $min = date('i', $unixtime);*/

        $year = date('Y', $unixtime);
    $month = date('m', $unixtime);
    $day = date('j', $unixtime);
    $hour = date('G', $unixtime);
    $min = date('i', $unixtime);

    $date = 0;
    $date = $year << 20;
    $date |= $month << 16;
    $date |= $day <<11;
    $date |= $hour <<6;
    $date |= $min;

    return $date;
}

/**
 * Converts a bitwise datestamp to a standard unixtime stamp
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $timestamp
 * @return void
 */
function convert_bitwise_to_unixtime($timestamp)
{
    $dateline = array();

    $dateline['year'] = ($timestamp & 0xfff00000) >> 20;
    $dateline['month'] =($timestamp & 0x000f0000) >> 16;
    $dateline['day'] = ($timestamp & 0x0000f800) >> 11;
    $dateline['hour'] = ($timestamp & 0x000007c0) >> 6;
    $dateline['min'] = ($timestamp & 0x0000003f);

    return mktime($dateline['hour'], $dateline['min'], 0, $dateline['month'], $dateline['day'], $dateline['year']);
}
```

Can anyone help me convert this to .Net in the simplest of fashions. Ideally i would write an extension method to the datetime object to return a "bitwise?" object and an extension methods to turn a bitwise timestamp into a datetime timestamp. I would ideally end up with something similar to bel..

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static BitWiseDateStamp ToBitWiseDateStamp(this DateTime timeStamp)
    {
        return BitWiseDateStamp.New(timeStamp);
    }

}

public class BitWiseDateStamp
{
    private string _value;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }


    public static BitWiseDateStamp New(DateTime date)
    {
        var b = new BitWiseDateStamp();

        var bitWiseStr = string.Empty; 

        //= Convert to bitwise string format...

        b.Value = bitWiseStr;
        return b;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this._value;
    }

    public DateTime ToDateTime()
    {
        var date = DateTime.MinValue;
        var dateStr = string.Empty;

        //== Convert bitwise string to date string respresenation

        DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, out date);
        return date;
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Cheers,

Nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but won't this do?

```
public class BitwiseDateStamp
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public BitwiseDateStamp(DateTime dt)
    {
        this._value = dt.Year << 20;
        this._value |= dt.Month << 16;
        this._value |= dt.Day << 11;
        this._value |= dt.Hour << 6;
        this._value |= dt.Minute;
    }

    public BitwiseDateStamp() : this(DateTime.Now)
    {   
    }

    public DateTime ToDateTime()
    {
        int year = this._value >> 20;
        int month = (this._value & 0x000f0000) >> 16;
        int day = (this._value & 0x0000f800) >> 11;
        int hour = (this._value & 0x000007c0) >> 6;
        int minute = this._value & 0x0000003f;

        return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this._value.ToString();
    }
}
```

and

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static BitwiseDateStamp ToBitwiseDateStamp(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return new BitwiseDateStamp(dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i didnt even realise that it was that easy to convert. Here i am trying to work in a complelty different manor. Sometimes the answer is staring you in the face. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a need in BitWiseDateStamp class. That could be implemented like that:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static ulong ToDateStamp(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return (dt.Year << 20 | dt.Month << 16 | dt.Day << 11 | dt.Hour << 6 |                        dt.Minute);
    }

    public static DateTime FromDateStamp(this ulong stamp)
    {
        return new DateTime((stamp & 0xfff00000) >> 20,
                            (stamp & 0x000f0000) >> 16,
                            (stamp & 0x0000f800) >> 11,
                            (stamp & 0x000007c0) >> 6,
                            (stamp & 0x0000003f),
                            0 // 0 seconds
                           );
    }

}
```

Comment: Although this would also fit the bill I am using an actual object as the integration to the API service is being built in a seperate assembly that will be used throughout other projects. What we need is an actual object being passed in as opposed to using only extension methods. This help minimize user error in passing incorrect values into the methods that use this. Now I added the extension method into my own assembly (seperate project) to just bind the ToBitwiseDate an extension to datetime. I really appreciate the time you took to write this response. Cheers, Nico